# How to call the Serapi from a project - localhost in Nodejs and Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

How can I call the URL?

**node-controller.js**

```
const SerpApi = require('google-search-results-nodejs');
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch("serpApi-key");

const params = {
  api_key: "secret_api_key",
  q: "Coffee",
  location: "Austin, Texas, United States",
  hl: "en",
  gl: "us",
  google_domain: "google.com"
};
const callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

  
router.post('/seekSearchApi/serpapi.com/search.json', seekSearchApi);
 module.exports = router;
function seekSearchApi(req, res) { 
search.json(params, callback);
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/seekSearchApi/serpapi.com/search.json', require('./server/nodejs-serverapi'));
```

I tried to call the API using various URLs like -

```
http://localhost:3003/serpapi.com/search.json/?q= "Coffee",&location= "Austin, Texas, United States",&hl= "en",&gl= "us",&google_domain= "google.com"
```

But it did not work. What can I try next?

Comment: your query seems to be wrong try this `http://localhost:3003/seekSearchApi/serpapi.com/search.json/?q=Coffee&location=Austin,Texas,United%20States&hl=en&gl=us&google_domain=google.com`

Comment: The above query doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong in my code @DankDizaster

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Please be more specific and detailed if you can. Have you tried calling this from a browser or curl? What is the HTTP response code and body when you do?